# How do I use DI on asp.net web api project not .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, webapi2

The following documentation shows how to configure cosmonaut for a .net core project.

https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut

```
Registering the CosmosStores in ServiceCollection for DI support

 var cosmosSettings = new CosmosStoreSettings("<<databaseName>>", "<<cosmosUri>>", "<<authkey>>");

serviceCollection.AddCosmosStore<Book>(cosmosSettings);

//or just by using the Action extension

serviceCollection.AddCosmosStore<Book>("<<databaseName>>", "<<cosmosUri>>", "<<authkey>>", settings =>
{
    settings.ConnectionPolicy = connectionPolicy;
    settings.DefaultCollectionThroughput = 5000;
    settings.IndexingPolicy = new IndexingPolicy(new RangeIndex(DataType.Number, -1),
        new RangeIndex(DataType.String, -1));
});
```

How do I do for an old webpi project?

Comment: From the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web Api 2 doesn't come with out of box dependency injection, you can use 3rd party dependency injection packages like Autofac and Ninject etc, or you can create Cosmonaut's singleton class for use too if you don't want to use dependency injection at all.

Note: As per their [docs](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/cosmonaut/latest/cosmonaut.pdf), Cosmonaut instance should be used as singleton instances per entity.

**UPDATE**

Implementation of a generic Singleton class where T is the type of entity you are asking for the instance of,

```
public sealed class CosmosStoreSingleton<T>
{
    private static ICosmosStore<T> instance = null;

    public static ICosmosStore<T> Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance==null)
            {
                var cosmosSettings = new CosmosStoreSettings("<<databaseName>>", "<<cosmosUri>>", "<<authkey>>");
                instance = new CosmosStore<T>(cosmosSettings);
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll be glad to provide you with sample code if you want for resolving it through Autofac or custom Singleton class.

Comment: You should use locking when creating the singleton instance.

Comment: Yeah one should use that when the instance is not thread safe, but this cosmos store instance seems to be thread safe according to their documentation.